# Elasticsearch get all data with filters

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to get all data from elasticsearch with filters without pageable. Which way is the best to get it? I`v got default limit set to 2000. I read I should use scan but I dont know how I should use it. How I should use scan and scroll to get all data?

```
public Map searchByIndexParams(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());



        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));


        //access for many uids
        if(searchParams.getUids() != null){
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUids().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("uid", v)));
            });
        }


        //access for many categories
        if(searchParams.getCategories() != null){
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategories().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
            });
        }

       final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }


        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));


        final FacetedPage<AuctionIndex> search = auctionIndexRepository.search(searchQuery.build());


      response.put("content", search.map(index ->auctionRepository
              .findAuctionById(Long.valueOf(index.getId())))
              .getContent());

        return response;
    }
```

edit:

I`v got:

```
String scrollId = searchTemplate.scan(searchQuery.build(), 1000, false);

        Page<AuctionIndex> page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 15000L, AuctionIndex.class);
        Integer i = 0;
        if (page != null && page.hasContent()) {

            while(page.hasContent()){

                page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 15000L, AuctionIndex.class);

                if(page.hasContent()){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    i++;
                }


            }

        }
```

but iterate go to 166 and stop what`s wrong ?

Comment: Any idea whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

[Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html) is the best way to go through all the documents in the most efficient way. Using the `scroll_id` you can find a session that is stored on the server for your specific scroll request.

Here is a sample how you can using elasticsearch java scroll api in your code to fetch all the results matching your query.

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch(<INDEX>)
            .setQuery(<QUERY>)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
            .setScroll(SCROLL_TIMEOUT)
            .setSize(SCROLL_SIZE)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();

while (true) {
        searchResponse = client
                .prepareSearchScroll(searchResponse.getScrollId())
                .setScroll(SCROLL_TIMEOUT)
                .execute().actionGet();

        if (searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length == 0) {
            break; //Break condition: No hits are returned
        }

        for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {
             // process response
        }
    }
```

Sample using Spring-data-elasticsearch

```
@Autowired
private ElasticsearchTemplate searchTemplate;

String scrollId = searchTemplate.scan(<SEARCH_QUERY>, 1000, false);

Page<ExampleItem> page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, ExampleItem.class);
if (page != null && page.hasContent()) {
// process first batch
    while (page != null && page.hasContent()) {
        page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, ExampleItem.class);
        if (page != null && page.hasContent()) {
            // process remaining batches
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `ExampleItem` specifies the entity that is to be fetched.

Comment: Ok but how I use it with NativeSearchQueryBuilder ? It`s possible?

Comment: while (page != null && page.hasNext()) but page is not defined before so I dont know what it should be and in my project <SEARCH_QUERY> = searchQuery.build() ? ExampleItem = AuctionIndex?

Comment: You just needed to declare it before the while loop. updated.

Comment: page.hasNext() return false